# How to sequentially push into array from MYSQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

The php and js are the following:

```js
    createRoomTable()

    function createRoomTable(){
      $.post('../include/returnRoomTable.php',{
        //nothing to transmit
      }).then((returnedTableMarkup) => {
        returnedTableMarkup = JSON.parse(returnedTableMarkup)
        console.log("data from returnRoomTable.php is ", returnedTableMarkup)
        //$('#roomTableOutput').html(returnedTableMarkup)
      })
    }
```

```html
<?php
session_start();

try{
  $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXXX',
  'XXXX','XXXXXX');
}catch(PDOException $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}

$allRooms = $connection->query("
SELECT name
FROM raum
")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

$indexLimit = count($allRooms);
$allSeats = [];
for($index = 0; $index < $indexLimit; $index++){
  $allSeats =  array_push($connection->query("
  SELECT nummer
  FROM arbeitsplatz
  WHERE raum = '".$allRooms[$index]."'
  ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM));
}

echo json_encode ($allSeats);

?>
```

So currently, consolelog says the array is "null".
What I need is a flexible, two-dimensional array ("$allSeats") which takes each iteration from the MYSQL query and puts it into this array.
The problem is that I'm not very experiences with arrays in php, and I'm out of ideas how I can accomplish this.

Comment: you could do this much more efficiently with a single query using an INNER JOIN. Just make sure you order the query by room and then by number.

Comment: What shows if you call the php page without JS? Just in the browser.

Comment: USE THIS QUERY:- `$allRooms = $connection->query("SELECT raum.name,arbeitsplatz.nummer FROM raum INNER JOIN arbeitsplatz ON arbeitsplatz.raum = raum.name"))->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));`

Comment: I think you should be using `.done`, not `.then`

Comment: Also I suggest you check the syntax for array_push - check what parameters it expects and what it returns. You are not using it correctly, yet it's trivial to look it up. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: @ADyson What? But I want to push $currentQuery into $allSeats, and according to the manual, I put the array I want to push into first, and second comes the value/array I want to push. What am I doing wrong then?

Comment: "ccording to the manual, I put the array I want to push into first, and second comes the value/array I want to push". Yes that's correct. But that's not what your code does. `$allSeats = array_push($connection->query("
  SELECT nummer
  FROM arbeitsplatz
  WHERE raum = '".$allRooms[$index]."'
  ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM))` - 1) you only give it one parameter. (the query result). 2) the parameter you're giving it is the value/array you want to push, not the one you want to push _into_, and 3) also according to the manual the function returns an integer...

Comment: ...so in conclusion you're pushing nothing into the wrong array and then setting $allSeats to an integer value. If you think that where you've put $allSeats in your code is equivalent to "put the array I want to push into first" then you seem to be confused about quite a basic principle - giving an argument to a function and receiving its return value?

Comment: Correct syntaxes would be either 1) `array_push($allSeats, $connection->query(" SELECT nummer FROM arbeitsplatz WHERE raum = '".$allRooms[$index]."' ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM))` or 2) the less verbose equivalent `$allSeats[] = $connection->query(" SELECT nummer FROM arbeitsplatz WHERE raum = '".$allRooms[$index]."' ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM))`. As it stands, I think you've mangled these two options together into something invalid.

Comment: As a matter of fact, unless you've got at least PHP 7.3 then I think your code will be throwing an error as it stands. See https://eval.in/1053500 - I've written a demo of incorrect and correct usage. If you uncomment the incorrect version and press Submit you'll see the crash. The changelog in the docs mentions this - "7.3.0....This function can now be called with only one parameter. Formerly, at least two parameters have been required."

Comment: And since 7.3 is still in testing and not formally released, I'd be surprised if you're running it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found a solution to my problem myself:

The php now looks like this:

```html
<?php
session_start();

try{
  $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=arbeitsplatzverwaltung',
  'verwalter','N7pY1OTl2gaBbc51');
}catch(PDOException $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}

$allRooms = $connection->query("
SELECT name
FROM raum
")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

$indexLimit = count($allRooms);
$allSeats = [];

for($index = 0; $index < $indexLimit; $index++){
  $currentQuery = $connection->query("
  SELECT nummer
  FROM arbeitsplatz
  WHERE raum = '".$allRooms[$index][0]."'
  ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

  array_push($allSeats, $currentQuery);
}
/*
$allSeats[] = $connection->query("
 SELECT nummer
 FROM arbeitsplatz WHERE raum = '".$allRooms[$index]."'
 ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);*/

echo json_encode ($allSeats);

?>
```

And when I output this in my JS, I get an array of arrays containing the values.